# How do I resolve the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: validator is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick where the function (validator) IS defined?

Tags: javascript, uncaught-reference-error

I have a function called validator that requires users of our website to read the disclaimer and check a checkbox showing they Accept the disclaimer.  Then it will open a GIS map upon clicking the Accept button.  My code seemingly works in CodePen (it says the code has no errors, although it does not load the URL upon hitting Accept but I don't know if CodePen is supposed to be able to do that) but in our CMS I'm getting an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: validator is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick.

I don't understand this error because the function (validator) is defined.  I'm a JavaScript beginner so I'm likely missing something obvious to the rest of you.

[image]

[image]

I have the code residing in a Custom Content item in our CMS that is referenced from the web page via the class.  I contacted Support and they confirmed this is the correct way to reference the code.  I use this same method to add custom CSS and it always works so I think this is probably correct.

I then thought that maybe the function is not loading into the page until after it's being called in my HTML, so I pasted the function into the HTML inside script tags via adding it into the page content area widget before my HTML where it's called, but that didn't work.  I didn't really think it would but was throwing spaghetti at the wall because I don't know what else to try.  I don't have access to the main codebase because we are just a tenant using this CMS for our government agency and the vendor doesn't help with troubleshooting code.

```html
<form name="agreement" style="text-align: center;"> <input type="checkbox" id="agreement" name="agreement"> <br> <br> <input type="button" value="Accept" onclick="validator()">  </form>
```

```js
function validator() {
if (document.getElementById("agreement").checked) {
location.assign(
"http://galvcountymaps.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=d619c89878cd4c399b376b51996a7541"
);
} else {
alert("You must check on the agreement.");
}
}
```

Here is the URL to the page I'm working on:  https://www.galvestoncountytx.gov/county-offices/engineering-floodplain-permitting-right-of-way/engineering/gis-mapping/interactive-county-map-test

Thank you,
Holly

Comment: You haven't provided any code. Please include a minimal reproducible example so that we may have some idea of what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the screenshot counted as code.  Here you go:  HTML <form name="agreement" style="text-align: center;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="agreement" name="agreement">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Accept" onclick="validator()">
  <!--<h2 style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://galvcountymaps.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=d619c89878cd4c399b376b51996a7541">Interactive County Map</a></h2>-->
</form>

Comment: console.log(document);
//const document = window.document;
function validator() {
  if (document.getElementById("agreement").checked) {
    location.assign(
      "http://galvcountymaps.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=d619c89878cd4c399b376b51996a7541"
    );
  } else {
    alert("You must check on the agreement.");
  }
}

Comment: I'll admit, I only looked at the circled item in the screenshot, but screenshots are frowned upon because they are not easily searched or recreated.

Comment: Please update your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: *I thought the screenshot counted as code.* <-- Unfortunately, no. We can't copy/paste from a picture and we can't try your code if it's a picture.

Comment: Which specific line(s) of code is the the error pointing to?

Comment: Yes, we can see it, but we can't search it or copy/paste it. Please paste your code as text into your question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know.  I just pasted in my HTML and JavaScript but I didn't see a way  to format it.  Still looking...

Comment: Have you included the script file in the html page?

Comment: @mykaf  it appears to not like the line in the HTML with the onclick:  Uncaught ReferenceError: validator is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (interactive-county-map-test:1376:63)

Comment: Have you tried using an event listener instead of an in-line event? But it says the function isn't defined, which makes me wonder if the JS file is "linked."

Comment: @mykaf yes I included the script in the HTML page via a custom content item that is referenced on the page (this is how it is done in our CMS because we don't have access to the html, only widgets, including custom content items which are similar to widgets, allowing you to add snippets of code into the page which you would otherwise not have access to add)

Comment: @mykaf, no, I'll look into trying the event listener.

Comment: Okay @HollyFortenberry, Hope that works for you

Comment: The code as you've included here seems to work fine. That makes me wonder if the JS isn't linked correctly. Are there other functions in your JS file? Do they execute as expected?

Comment: @mykaf  This is my only function.  I'm going to remove it all and just try a simple popup to see if that works.  Yes, I also thought it must not be linked correctly so I put in a ticket with our vendor and they said it is indeed linked correctly.  But frankly, most of their technicians don't know anything about front end code, not even HTML or CSS; so I'm don't always feel super confident in their response.

Comment: Perhaps you could add another very simple function to the JS and call it from the html when the page loads?

Comment: @bharti  I tried your idea of using the event listener but it didn't work either.  I'm going to reach back out to our website vendor in case there is something blocking my code.  Thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: @mykaf, thank you for that suggestion.  I'll try that.  I'm not sure how that would work since I'm a beginner but will definitely look into it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct but here is another way which you can try:-

```js
function validator() {
  console.log("hii")
  // Your validation logic here
}

  document.getElementById('acceptButton').addEventListener('click', validator);
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Accept" id="acceptButton" />
```